# GoogleWebRtc too low bitrate

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webrtc

After video call starts quality is too low and frames dropping. Even though i set everything  to max- limit like :

```
self.peerConnection.setBweMinBitrateBps(300000, currentBitrateBps: 1000000, maxBitrateBps: 3000000)
```

And in sdp i added b=AS: 5000000. (i know this is too big but i started from smaller values and end up with this.)

And webrtc log output like:

```
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1112): Incoming frame dropped due to that the encoder is blocked.
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1380): Drop Frame: target bitrate 145093, input frame rate 16
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1380): Drop Frame: target bitrate 145093, input frame rate 16
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1380): Drop Frame: target bitrate 145093, input frame rate 16
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1380): Drop Frame: target bitrate 145093, input frame rate 16
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1380): Drop Frame: target bitrate 145093, input frame rate 16
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1120): Number of frames: captured 933, dropped (due to encoder         blocked) 35, interval_ms 60000
(frame_buffer2.cc:513): Frame with (picture_id:spatial_id) (23617:0) inserted after frame (23617:0) was handed off for decoding, dropping frame.
```

And after searching for "bitrate" keyword :

```
(bitrate_allocator.cc:394): Current BWE 300000
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1795): OnBitrateUpdated, bitrate 145264 stable bitrate = 145264 link allocation bitrate = 145264 packet loss 40 rtt 24
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1795): OnBitrateUpdated, bitrate 158753 stable bitrate = 158753 link allocation bitrate = 158753 packet loss 17 rtt 45
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1795): OnBitrateUpdated, bitrate 158280 stable bitrate = 158280 link allocation bitrate = 158280 packet loss 37 rtt 38
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1795): OnBitrateUpdated, bitrate 165802 stable bitrate = 165802 link allocation bitrate = 165802 packet loss 9 rtt 43
(video_stream_encoder.cc:1795): OnBitrateUpdated, bitrate 159169 stable bitrate = 159169 link allocation bitrate = 159169 packet loss 6 rtt 31
```

Can somebody pls help?